# how to create a matrix of array lists contains with objects in JAVA (eclipse)?

Tags: java, eclipse, generics, arraylist, 2d

I need to create a matrix that represents a board of a game.
every place in the matrix needs to be some kind of a list that contains objects (all kinds of actors of the game. players and other objects).
I need to do so cause in some point two objects might be on the same place of the matrix.
but eclipse doesn't aprrove to create a "generic array", so I can't initial the matrix with all the objects..what should i do?

Comment: Eclipse is just a development environment used to write programs in many different programming languages. Which programming language are you asking about? Show us your code.

Comment: The language is Java.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is somewhat vague. 
If you want the list-approach you probably want a list of list of list of Actors where **Actor** is the base-class (or interface) for your other classes (such as players and "other objects"). Then think of the lists as columns, rows and list of actors in the same position.

Example:

[image: Example of actors]

```
List<List<List<Actor>>> columns = new ArrayList<List<List<Actor>>>();
List<List<Actor>>> rows = new ArrayList<List<Actor>>();
List<Actor> actors = new ArrayList<Actor>
//Then pupulate the columns with rows and the rows with lists of actors
```

I would not recommend this scince this approach quickly gets out of hand. 
Instead create your own representation (which might have underlying lists or maps) of the board. Then you might end up with something like:

```
Board board = new Board(10,10);
Actor whiteQueen = new Queen();
Actor blackKing = new King();
board.addActor(8,2, whiteQueen);
board.addActor(8,2, blackKing);
```